# Replace valus in a string variable - Scala

Tags: string, scala, replace

I need a code to replace values in a string variable using scala.

[image]

My original value has "tax_id" and I need to replace it with "cpf".

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you explain how this data is represented is Scala, and what code you have tried that is not working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you are working with spark scala dataframes.

regexp_replace can work but you might end up unintentionally replacing other parts of your string. so a simple substring and concat should do...

e.g.:

```
val data = Seq(("1","tax_id_status_regular"),
("2","tax_id_status_error"),
("3","tax_id_status_irregular"))
.toDF("customerId", "taxIdStatus")

val result = data.withColumn("taxIdStatusNew",
concat(lit("cpf"), substring(col("taxIdStatus"), 7, 100)))

result.show(20,false)
+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|customerId|taxIdStatus            |taxIdStatusNew      |
+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|1         |tax_id_status_regular  |cpf_status_regular  |
|2         |tax_id_status_error    |cpf_status_error    |
|3         |tax_id_status_irregular|cpf_status_irregular|
+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!